# Maintain height of the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a client who wants to do a website with specific height for the content part.

**The Question:**

Is there any way that when the text is long / reach the maximum height of the content part, then a new page is created for the next text.

Within my knowledge, somehow I know this can't be done.

Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to look into something like jQuery paging with tabs

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-tabs-paging/

Unfortunately you would need to figure out the maximum number of characters you want to allow in the content pane and anything after that would need to be put into another tab.  You can hide the tab and use just a link instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without more knowledge on what you're development is, this is a difficult question to answer.  Are you looking to create a different page entirely, or just different sections on a page?

The former can be done using server-side code (e.g. Rails), and dynamically serving out pages (e.g. Google results are split across many page).

The latter can be done with Javascript and/or CSS.  A simple example is:

```
<div id="the_content" style="overflow:hidden;width:200px;height:100px">
   Some really long text...
</div>
```

This would create a "scroll" bar and just not disrupt the flow of the page.  In Javascript (e.g. JQuery), you'll be able to split the content into "tabs".

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

(Almost) everything is possible, but your intuitions are right in that this can't be done easily or in a way that makes any sense.

If I were in your position, I would go up to the client and present advantages and disadvantages to breaking it up. Advantages include the fact that you'd be able to avoid long pages and that with some solutions to this problem, the page will load faster. Disadvantages include the increased effort (i.e., billable hours) it would take to accomplish this, the lack of precedent for it resulting in users being confused, and losses to SEO (you're splitting keywords amongst `n` pages).

This way, you're not shooting down the client's idea, and in the likely case the client retreats from his position, he will go away thinking that he's just made a smart choice by himself and everyone goes away happy.

If you're intent on splitting it up into pages, you can do it on the backend by either literally structuring your content into pages or applying some rule (e.g., cut a page off at the first whole paragraph after 1000 characters) to paginate the results. On the frontend, you could use hashtags to allow Javascript to paginate the results. You could even write an extensible library that "paginates" any text node. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if one didn't exist already.